# Vanishing of the cotangent complex for non-perfect algebras

Tags: ac.commutative-algebra, cotangent-complex

Let $k$ be a perfect field of characteristic $p>0$. If $R$ is a perfect $k$-algebra, then the cotangent complex $L_{R/k}$ vanishes (the Frobenius is zero and induces an isomorphism on $L_{R/k}$ since $R$ is perfect). Is the converse true? Namely, if $L_{R/k}$ vanishes, then is $R$ perfect over $k$? I suspect not, but I can't find a counterexample. What happens if $k$ is a field of characteristic $0$?

Answer (score 3):

see Bhargav Bhatt's example (suggested by Gabber) of an imperfect ring with trivial cotangent complex

http://www-personal.umich.edu/~bhattb/papers.html

Comment: Thanks. It still leaves open the case when k has characteristic 0, though. What happens then?

Comment: @skd: Judging by Bhatt's note, it looks like it is not known.